# Need Assistance with VBSCRIPT to capture screenshots of user's desktop

Tags: windows, vbscript, screenshot

I am a novice when it comes to object oriented program.  That said, I have been trying to construct a vbscript that will capture a screenshot of the desktop and immediately save it to a folder I specify.   Here is the code I have so far:

' START

```
 Dim screenSize 

 screenSize = New screenSize.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y)

 Dim screenGrab

 screenGrab = New screenGrab.Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width,   my.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

 Dim g 

 g = g.System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)

 dim copyS

 copyS = Graphics.CopyPixels4.PaintEventArgs

 dim copyS2

 copyS2 = copyS.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation)

 dim saveTo

 saveTo = screenGrab.Save("C:\temp\screenGrab.bmp")
```

' END

I prefer to keep this in VBSCRIPT as this script will be incorporated into an existing vbscript I created.  I currently get an error at line 3 stating "class not defined 'screensize".  I am also concerned that even if I fix the error at line 3 I may run into other syntax issues afterward.  The overall intent of the script is to 1) get the screen dimensons ; 2) perform the screenshot ; 3) and save the file to a destination.  I am open to any suggestions to make this work.

I appreciate any help I can get at this point.  Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you have messed VB.NET with VBScript. screenSize, screenGrab, System.Drawing.Graphics - there are no such classes in VBScript by default.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have messed VB.NET with VBScript.
screenSize, screenGrab, System.Drawing.Graphics - there are no such classes in VBScript by default.

What I'd suggest is to use some screen capture ActiveX (google it).
Or create your own ActiveX with VB6 by using code like [this](https://workspaces.codeproject.com/rajesh-naik-ponda-goa/capturing-screenshot-of-desktop-programatically-in/code/blob/master/GetWindowScreenshot/WindowScreenshot.bas). Create new ActiveX project in VB6, add that module and compile.
And remember to run `regsvr32.exe youractivex.ocx` before using it in your script.